# Place item distinct value and count in Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq, data-structures

Let's say I have a `List<string>`:

```
Apples
Apples
Apples
Apples
Bread
Bread
Milk
```

I would like to know if there is a way on how I can sort this into a Dictionary or any other data structure you think would be better.

For example:

```
Apple : 4
Bread : 2
Milk  : 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

- Group the items (using Linq's [GroupBy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby)) by their string value (the *names*)
- use the [ToDictionary()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary) method to produce the final result

  - use the Grouping `Key` for the Dictionary `Key` (the names are unique)
  - the Groups item count will provide the value

```
List<string> myConsumables = new List<string>() {
    "Apples", "Bread", "Apples", "Apples", "Milk", "Apples", "Bread", "Apples", "Milk"
};

var myDictionary = myConsumables.GroupBy(s => s).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Test it with:

```
myDictionary.ToList().ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine($"{d.Key}: {d.Value}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have a list of strings. Now there are different possibilities.

**Solution 1: Use simple iteration**

```
//declare a dic of string, int
Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string,int>

//iterate loop 
foreach (var i in lst)
{
     if (dic.ContainsKey(i))
     {
         dic[i]++;
     }
     else
     {
         dic.Add(i, 1);
     }
}
```

**Solution 2: Use Linq Group By**

```
//First group by the items and then transform the solution into dictionary 
var dic = lst.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(y => y.Key, z => z.Count());
```